# Conduit that checks file header

Tags: haskell, header, bytestring, conduit

I'd like to use `Conduit` in a setting where I read a binary file, check that it has the correct header, and then work on the remaining data in the file.

Trying to write a conduit that checks the header and then streams the rest of the data on to the following conduits I run into trouble. I have them live in a `Either String` monad for some exception handling. Here's a simplified version of the code (I'm aware there's a `Condiut.Attoparsec` module, but for now I'd like to write it myself):

```
import Conduit (ConduitM, mapC, mapM_C, takeWhileCE) 
import Data.ByteString.Conversion (toByteString')

separator :: ByteString
separator = toByteString' '#' 

check :: ByteString -> Either String ()

confirmHeader :: ConduitM ByteString ByteString (Either String) ()
confirmHeader = do
  takeWhileC (/= separator) .| mapM_C check
  mapC id
```

`separator` is a predefined `ByteString` that signals the end of the header. The line `mapC id` is supposed to pass on the rest of the stream if the header checks out. I left out the nonimportant details of `check`.

The part checking the header works. The last line, however, apart from looking inelegant and non-idiomatic, doesn't work. Running something like

```
runConduit $ yield (toByteString' "header#rest") .| confirmHeader .| sinkList
```

Gives `Right []` rather than `Right ["rest"]`, as I had hoped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `takeWhileC (/= separator)` is taking the whole `ByteString`: it's not working on chunks of `ByteString`s! You can use `Data.Conduit.Binary` to work on individual bytes of the stream. The below code works "as expected" I believe.

```hs
module Main (main) where

import           Conduit
import           Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import           Data.ByteString.Conversion (toByteString')
import           Data.Char (ord)
import qualified Data.Conduit.Binary as B
import           GHC.Word (Word8)

separator :: Word8
separator = toEnum $ ord '#'

check :: ByteString -> Either String ()
check _ = Right ()

confirmHeader :: ConduitM ByteString ByteString (Either String) ()
confirmHeader = do
  B.takeWhile (/= separator) .| mapM_C check
  B.drop 1 -- drop separator which stayed in stream
  mapC id

main :: IO ()
main = print . runConduit $
  yield (toByteString' "header#rest") .| confirmHeader .| sinkList
```

And the output:

```
[nix-shell:/tmp]$ ghc C.hs -fforce-recomp -Wall -Werror -o Main && ./Main
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( C.hs, C.o )
Linking Main ...
Right ["rest"]
```

Comment: Great! As a small detail I opted for takeWhileCE instead for now, but I'll benchmark it against Conduit.Binary.

Comment: `takeWhileCE` should work: I actually wanted to use that but I forgot its name and Conduit.Binary came up first on hackage.

Comment: Ok! Incidentally, can you think of something more elegant than `mapC id`, or is that standard? Apologies if this is now off topic..

Comment: I think `mapC id` is canonical: you can see conduit author use it here https://www.snoyman.com/blog/2017/05/worst-function-in-conduit